# Is it possible to display `PageNotFound` component in dedicated `router-outlet`?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have scenario when I want to display `PageNotFound` component in dedicated router outlet. Is there a way to do that?

The reason for this is to display error message components (404 is one of them) outside of main application UI scope - without navigation menus, logos, headers etc.

Template:

```
 <div class="myapp">
    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
       routerLink="/login">Login</a> |

    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
       routerLink="/home">Home</a> | 

    <a routerLinkActive="active" 
      routerLink="/catalog">Catalog</a> 

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="errors">
     <router-outlet name="errors"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

relevant routing:

```
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, outlet:"errors"}
```

I want `PageNotFoundComponent` to be rendered in `errors` outlet. Right now it only causes *Cannot match any routes* error

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts

I need it to work both to navigate from outside, as well as by router navigation (will display different error component, but still in the same `errors` outlet);